# data_mapper find number of rows

Tags: sinatra, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I can't find an answer for this elsewhere, so I'm asking here:

How do I "`SELECT COUNT`" with data_mapper?

What I've tried:

1. `MyClass.count`
2. `MyClass.size`
3. `MyClass.all.count`
4. `MyClass.all.size`

What does work is:

```
ids = []
MyClass.all.each do |class|
    ids << class.id
end
ids.size
```

But that's a bit horrible. Anyone know any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try was right but if you look at the documentation, count is a aggregate function and therefore you need to install/require dm-aggregates.

> Aggregate functions
>
> For the following to work, you need to have dm-aggregates required.